# Random Hover Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can you randomize hover effects?

For example:

```
<p>test</p>

p:hover {
background: yellow;
}

p:hover:
background: red;
}
```

Please note that the above is for-example only. The question is, how can you randomize hover effects, so it shows the `background:yellow;` and `background:red;` once in random order on the `onmouseover`?

There should not be any order, like for example: on first hover - one class is added, on second - another. It should be **completely random**.

Comment: Create different classes and change it between them...

Comment: How can you toggle a specific class in random order? Please add a working example. Thanks.

Comment: Not using classes, but you could probably assign a random color on mouseover using the JQ CSS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553036/random-color-in-jquery

Comment: So Math.random should do it...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following function to get random colors and use mouseover event to change the background color.

```
function getRandomColor () {
 var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
 var color = '#';
 for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
 }
 return color;
    }
})

$( "p" ).mouseover(function() {
$(this).css("background",getRandomColor());
});
```

Please check this [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/1/).

Comment: That's an interesting method of generating the colors.

Comment: @Aneesh, this is very interesting method for generate random color, but I think this is not good way to generate color. it may be matched with text or fore-color, I think pre defined color should be best in CSS or JS

Answer (score 0):

You could add a random class to the element on hover and remove it when the hover event is done.

If you have the following CSS:

```
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

You could use the follow jQuery code example:

```
// Declare all classes that can be used in the random selection
var classes = ['yellow', 'red'];

$("p").hover(
  function() {
    // Select a random class
    var randomClass = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)];

    $(this).addClass(randomClass);
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass();
  }
);
```

You can check an example on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4wu6t89/).

The random selection is made on the `classes` array using the `Math.random()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("p[data-random]").mouseover(function(){
 max_value=5;
 random_value= Math.floor((Math.random() * max_value) + 1);
 $(this).attr("data-random",random_value);
});
})
```

```css
p[data-random]{
 padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

p[data-random]:hover {
 cursor: pointer
}

p[data-random="1"]:hover {
 background: yellow;
}
p[data-random="2"]:hover {
 background: red;
}
p[data-random="3"]:hover {
 background: black;
}
p[data-random="4"]:hover {
 background: white;
}
p[data-random="5"]:hover {
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-random="1">Hello</p>
```

This is best way to do random effect on background, here I have considered 5 colors for random effect.

Answer (score -1):

You should play with setting different classes using javascript.

For example something like that (jquery) :

```
 var randomClasses = ['class1','class2','class3'];
$('p').mouseover(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass(function() {
   var randomColor = randomClasses[getRandomInt(0,randomClasses.length-1)];
   return randomColor;
 });    
})


function getRandomInt(min, max)
{
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: you are just toggling between two states

Comment: Updated to random version

Comment: Perhaps a demo of this code working would improve this answer?