# Insert a random number in to an inline style for a background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to output a random number between 0-360 in to and inline style tag using javascript or jquery but I can't seem to figure out how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Fiddle attached here - 
https://jsfiddle.net/4c59f6aw/

```
<div style="background-color:hsl('value to go here', 100%, 50%)"></div>
```

Comment: You forgot to share the JavaScript code.

Comment: Yes, because that's what I'm unsure of.

Comment: Still, please show us what you tried so far, otherwise it's just a "please code this for me!"

Comment: But, do you need help with every single step involved, like writing a basic selector to select the DIV?

Comment: For example, we can just guess whether the percentage values from the second and third hsl() attributes are fixed (so they can be set from the script that sets the random number), or if they have to be variable, so the values before the script sets the randum number have to be taken into account

Comment: Yes, that's it. The last two values are fixed and will not change. Basically, I have a carousel that has a set background colour for each slide. But I don't want every slide to be the same colour. So I just want to input a random number in the first hsl value. I was going to base it off this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553036/random-color-in-jquery - and change the rgba value to hsl - however that targets a div and I just want to insert a random number in to an inline style.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do is, is to add the CSS via JavaScript.

The first line takes a number that is random (up to 360) and the second and third line get the `#box` div and add the color dynamically. So every page refresh, a different color will be added to the box.

The `background-color` notation might look strange. It's called *template strings* and you can read more about it [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

I don't know why you tagged jQuery to your question, as it is a library and needs to be downloaded by the client. It's not needed to achieve the result that you want to.

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);

var myElement = document.querySelector("#box");
myElement.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${randomNumber}, 100%, 50%)`;
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: The random range in `Math.floor(Math.random() * 360)` is 0 to 359, as `Math.random()` is 1-exclusive. The Randomization part should look something like this: `Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.hello');

for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var color = Math.floor((Math.random() * 361) + 0);

  elements[i].style.background = 'hsl('+color+', 100%, 50%)';
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Comment: In order to allow other minimal values not starting with 1 (the OP requested the random number between ß and 360), the randomization code should be something like `Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);`

Answer (score 0):

Check this code snipet

> Using Jquery

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    
     $('#change').css({'background-color': 'hsl('+randomIntFromInterval(0,255)+', 100%, 50%)'});    
  });

  function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="change" style="background-color:hsl(126, 100%, 50%)"></div>
<button>Change</button>
```

> Using Javascript

```js
function change(){
  var div = document.getElementById('change');
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl('+randomIntFromInterval(0,255)+', 100%, 50%)';
}
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="change" style="background-color:hsl(123, 100%, 50%)"></div>
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Adding jQuery is overkill for this.

Comment: @Roy But as the question says "using javascript or jquery" . If already using jquery

Comment: @Roy I have added both the example :)

Comment: Hi Aman, thanks for that. I like the JQuery example. However I see you're using a click function to trigger the colour change. Would it be possible to set the colour on load?

Comment: Yes it can, just take it out from the click event

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I'm after. Do you know why if you have two div's the other doesn't get affected - https://jsfiddle.net/vzgxy1gn/1/

Comment: because you are using id which can be defined one time only. If you want for multiple just replace class instead of id. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/vzgxy1gn/4/

Answer (score -2):

Pure Javascript solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ru0k20zb/)

```
function populate(number, multiplier) {
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:hsl(' + i * multiplier +',100%,50%)');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}
populate(4, 30);
```